# Уровни кэша процессора

Tags: память, кэширование

Возьмем пример:

```
L1 - 128Kb
L2 - 512Kb
L3 - 2Mb
```

Зачем нужно несколько уровней кэш памяти?

Почему скорость `L1 > L2 > L3` (разный SRAM дизайн?)?

Зачем нужно `L1i` для инструкций и `L1d` для данных?

Как рассчитывается оптимальный размер и количество кэш уровней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Зачем нужно несколько уровней кэш памяти?

Если бы могли, то весь кэш сделали бы L1. Да и вообще, все ОЗУ затащили бы в процессор в виде кэша. Но тогда процессор будет много потреблять и расплавится (при заданной технологии производства и допусках).

> Почему скорость L1 > L2 > L3 (разный SRAM дизайн?)?

Опять же чтобы процессор не расплавился.

> Зачем нужно L1i для инструкций и L1d для данных?

Теперь же две очереди, отдельно для инструкций, отдельно для данных. Вот и кэша два.

> Как рассчитывается оптимальный размер и количество кэш уровней?

Там ничего особо не рассчитывается. Сколько места на кристалле остается после размещения ядер, все отдается под кэши разных уровней.

UPD1:

А вообще-то есть форумы разработчиков процессоров, даже русскоязычные (да-да не смейтесь). На крайний случай есть форумы разработчиков плат, раньше это было на каких-нибудь телесистемах а сейчас не знаю где, но можно найти. Спросите там, там Вам подробнее объяснят.

Answer (score 2):

Основная проблема в обеспечении максимальной загрузки процессора и минимизации простоев из-за загрузки данных из памяти.

Несколько уровней кэша различаются скоростью доступа в первую очередь. Уровневое кэширование позволяет оптимизировать загрузку данных из основной памяти и держать для процессора нужные страницы "под рукой".

Тут хорошая аналогия склад - магазин - холодильник - тарелка (кэширование продуктов).

Подробно кэши описаны у Танненбаума (Архитектура ЭВМ).